# Ignore ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick warning

Tags: c++, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

The code below catches not only errors but also some warnings with some specific inputs. Is there any way to ignore all the warnings instead of checking them in the catch block? I know I can use `+profile "*"` on terminal, but I have no idea about what to tackle it in C++.

```
try {
    Blob buff = Blob(input, inLen);
    pImage->read(buff);
} catch (Exception &error) {
    cout << error.what() << endl;
    delete(pImage);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Warnings are not exception, so you can't catch them. You can edit ImageMagick's `log.xml` configuration file to redirect warnings to a file, or perhaps disable them.

Comment: I've seen this message in the catch block `Magick: Invalid cHRM red point () reported by coders/png.c:1106 (PNGWarningHandler)`. isn't it a warning?

Comment: Ah. Perhaps I'm wrong. I'll post an possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading [Exception.cpp](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/Magick%2B%2B/lib/Exception.cpp) correctly, `Magick::Exception` is too generic. Try isolating the warnings from the errors.

```cpp
try {
    Magick::Blob buff = Magick::Blob(input, inLen);
    pImage->read(buff);
} catch (Magick::Warning &warning) {
    // Ignore, or log
} catch (Magick::Error &error) {
    cout << error.what() << endl;
    delete(pImage);
    return -1;
}
```